# Возвращаемое значение std::for_each

Tags: c++

Посмотрел [реализацию `std::for_each`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/) и стало жутко интересно, почему данная функция возвращает функцию, которую мы передаём в 3-ем параметре? Это как-то используется?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Если в качестве третьего параметра вы используете функциональный объект, вы можете наделить этот функциональный объект внутренним состоянием и накапливать в нем какой-то интересующий вас результат. Затем, по завершении `std::for_each`, этот результат можно будет извлечь из возвращенной копии объекта.

Например

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

struct S
{
    int sum = 0;
    void operator()(int i) { sum += i; }
};

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::cout << std::for_each(std::begin(a), std::end(a), S()).sum << std::endl;
}
```

Ситуацию также можно рассмотреть с точки зрения той же дизайн-идиомы, которая присутствует в классических С-функциях типа `strcpy`, т.е. передаваемое "насквозь" значение можно также использовать для более компактной (сцепленной) записи последовательных вызовов `std::for_each` с одним и тем же (с точки зрения значения) функциональным объектом

```
int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int b[] = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int c[] = { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };

    std::cout << 
      std::for_each(std::begin(c), std::end(c), 
      std::for_each(std::begin(b), std::end(b),
      std::for_each(std::begin(a), std::end(a), S()))).sum << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Уважаемый AnT, скажите пожалуйста, в чем Вы видите преимущество этого метода перед гораздо более наглядным for? Дополнительно объявляемая структура + длинная и трудно воспринимаемая строка for_each + 2 библиотеки. Не слишком ли велики накладные расходы?,